# Installing Python QuantLib: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, quantlib

I'm trying to install QuantLib. The install seems to complete successfully, but when I then try and import it, I get an error message which says:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm downloading from pypi, saving it to my PC, and then using `!pip install filepath`, to do the install. I've tried installing QuantLib versions 1.21, 1.20, 1.18. Got the same error in all 3.

I'm using Spyder in Anaconda.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a broken installation still in your system.

Try running a small test: Create a new environment and install QuantLib there.

```
conda create --name test python=3.8
conda activate test
pip install QuantLib
echo import QuantLib as ql; print(ql.__version__) > test.py
python test.py
```